# How to get First character of FirstName Property from List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a Generic List and I want to get first character from each record usin LINQ or LAMBDA. My class is like:

```
public class User
{
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

I have fetched the records from Database and filled the records into the **List**. Now I want to get the First character of each record in the list so that I can create alphabetical filter for my front-end.

For example: *If my List's FirstName filed contains "George", "Abraham", "Zulu" etc... then my alphabetic filter should contain : "A", "G", "Z" ..*

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.............

Comment: Read the C# documentation? This is the kind of question I would ask in an inteview. For a trainee position. Basic LINQ select and basic String method call.

Comment: This question is perfectly clear and answerable.

Comment: Actually I am newbie with LAMBDA AND LINQ. I am willing to ask how to do such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var users = new List<User>();

...

List<char> firstLetters =
   users
   .Select(user => user.FirstName)
   .Where(firstName => firstName != null && firstName.Any())
   .Select(firstName => firstName[0])
   .ToList();
```

You say:

> so that I can create alphabetical filter for my front-end

That sounds like you might want *unique* characters, in which case you'd want to call `Distinct` as well, and maybe `OrderBy` if you want them in order:

```
List<char> firstLetters =
   users
   .Select(user => user.FirstName)
   .Where(firstName => firstName != null && firstName.Any())
   .Select(firstName => firstName[0])
   .Distinct()
   .OrderBy(ch => ch)
   .ToList();
```